Confused with radius of search_params in COSINE and HNSW
I have built a collection with index_param:
index_params.add_index( field_name="video_embed", index_type="HNSW", metric_type="COSINE", params={"M": 32, "efConstruction": 500}, )

And when I use client.search() the data existed in the collection with search_params:
search_params = { "metric_type": "COSINE", "params": { "radius": **0.1**, # Determines the threshold of least similarity. "range_filter":1.0, } }

I can get the data's self as a result, such as:
{"id": "data-self-id", "distance": 0.9999995827674866}
But, if I use search_params:
search_params = { "metric_type": "COSINE", "params": { "radius": **0.9**, # Determines the threshold of least similarity. "range_filter":1.0, } }

some data can not get themselves in results. In this condition, no result was returned.
And no range_filter has the same result.
This is a problem for me now. I can't search for the most similar results to filter existing data.
I have tried adjust the radius value, and on some data, I should set radius to 0.57805, if the value more than this, I can not get the data point itself in search result. And this value is not universally applicable.

It seems the "radius" and "range_filter" are not correctly set.
This document tells how to set the two parameters in different situations:
https://milvus.io/docs/single-vector-search.md#Range-search
For IP/COSINE metric, distance/similarity range is [1.0, -1.0], 1.0 is the most similar item.
For L2 metric, distance range is [0.0, +∞], 0.0 is the most similar item.
"radius" is equal to the "range_max", "range_filter" is equal to "range_min".
This graph shows how they work for range filtering:

So, for COSINE metric, you should set range_filtersmaller than radius:
search_params = { "metric_type": "COSINE", "params": { "radius": 1.0, # Determines the threshold of least similarity. "range_filter":0.9, } }

